# SAP HANA - Calculations in calculated columns

Tags: view, calculated-columns, hana

Is it possible to create a calculated column in calculation view which goes as follows?

Table A

```
Month       Amount
-----       ------    
1           1000
1           2000
2           3000
2           3500
```

Filter:

```
filter month={CurrentMonth}; // here CurrentMonth= 2
```

JSON output:

```
[{
previousMnthAmount:3000,

currentMnthAmount:6500
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose creating a Scripted Calculation View. In it, you can write SQLScript code for doing the necessary selects to get the data as you need it.

I see two options, based on what you want to use the view for:

1. Without input parameters.
2. With input parameters.

If you go for a view with input parameters, you might avoid some unnecessary calculations if you are really interested only in the data corresponding to one month.

#### Without parameters

Something along the lines of the following should work:

```sql
SELECT "T1"."MONTH", "T1"."TOTAL" AS "CURRENT_TOTAL", "T2"."TOTAL" AS "PREVIOUS_TOTAL" 
 FROM (SELECT "MONTH", SUM("AMOUNT") AS "TOTAL" FROM #TEST GROUP BY "MONTH") AS "T1" 
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT "MONTH", SUM("AMOUNT") AS "TOTAL" FROM #TEST GROUP BY "MONTH") AS "T2" 
 ON "T1"."MONTH" = "T2"."MONTH" + 1;
```

Where you should replace #TEST with your own table. Assuming that the following is the content of your table:
[image: Raw table content]

Then you would obtain the following results:
[image: Result without parameters]

If you wrap this into a view, then you can select from it and do a WHERE "MONTH" = 2 and obtain the values for the 2nd month.

#### With parameters

You can optimize the sql by removing the join altogether and doing filtered sums:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT SUM("AMOUNT") FROM #TEST WHERE "MONTH" = 2) AS "CURRENT_TOTAL", 
 (SELECT SUM("AMOUNT")  FROM #TEST WHERE "MONTH" = 1) AS "PREVIOUS_TOTAL" FROM DUMMY;
```

Of course, inside a calc. view, you should replace the fixed month values (2 and 1) with a parameter (e.g. 2 --> :IV_MONTH and 1 --> :IV_MONTH - 1). With the same content as above, you would obtain the following result:

[image: Result with parameters]

Comment: thank you for detailed explanation. We will try this

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the context of the question and this may not be an appropriate answer for the actual problem you are trying to solve. Apologies if not :-) 
If this is a data warehouse implementation and you want that information at the front end reporting, a more general approach is to have current_month and previous_month flags in the time dimension that are updated daily.  Then you can use those either in calculations or in a reporting front end.
 Then this will work with any view rather than creating a specific view for that one situation.